# Using accelerometer to detect iPad lock switch trigger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, autorotate, uidevice

So for complicated reasons I am managing view rotations myself, and am only implementing `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` as the autorotating orientation.

Anyway, when one clicks the screen lock on the iPad, the device will rotate to UIDeviceOrientationPortrait, which will cause my code to rotate, which I do not want to happen. For instance of the user is holding the device in "landscape mode", i.e. I have already manually rotated the UI to landscape mode, and he/she clicks the screen lock, it will rotate the UI to portrait mode, even though the user did not move the device at all.

So somehow I need a way to differentiate between rotations to portrait mode occuring from the screen lock, and those occuring from device rotation. As such, I would like somehow to use the accelerometer to detect whether or not the device was actually 'rotated' or whether the button was clicked.

Thanks!